# Errors in PLSQL -

Tags: sql, plsql, syntax

Morning,

I'm trying to write a script that will convert Unload tables (UNLD to HDL files) creating a flat file using PLSQL. I keep getting syntax errors trying to run it and would appreciate some help from an expert out there!

Here are the errors:

> Error(53,21): PLS-00330: invalid use of type name or subtype name
>
> Error(57,32): PLS-00222: no function with name 'UNLDTABLE' exists in this scope

Our guess is that the `unldTable` variable is being treated as a String, rather than a database table object (Not really expereinced in PLSQL)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE UNLD_TO_HDL (processComponent IN VARCHAR2)
IS
fHandle UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
concatData VARCHAR2(240);
concatHDLMetaTags VARCHAR2(240);
outputFileName VARCHAR2(240);
TYPE rowArrayType IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(240);
rowArray rowArrayType;
emptyArray rowArrayType;
valExtractArray rowArrayType;
hdlFileName VARCHAR2(240);
unldTable VARCHAR2(240);
countUNLDRows Number;
dataType VARCHAR2(240);
current_table VARCHAR2(30);
value_to_char VARCHAR2(240);

BEGIN 

SELECT HDL_FILE_NAME
INTO hdlFileName
FROM GNC_HDL_CREATION_PARAMS
WHERE PROCESS_COMPONENT = processComponent;

SELECT UNLD_TABLE
INTO unldTable
FROM GNC_HDL_CREATION_PARAMS
WHERE PROCESS_COMPONENT = processComponent
FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY;

SELECT LISTAGG(HDL_META_TAG,'|')
WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY HDL_META_TAG)
INTO concatHDLMetaTags
FROM GNC_MIG_CONTROL
WHERE HDL_COMP = processComponent;
    
SELECT DB_FIELD
BULK COLLECT INTO valExtractArray
FROM GNC_MIG_CONTROL
WHERE HDL_COMP = processComponent
ORDER BY HDL_META_TAG;

fHandle := UTL_FILE.FOPEN('./', hdlFileName, 'W');
UTL_FILE.PUTF(fHandle, concatHDLMetaTags + '\n');

SELECT num_rows INTO countUNLDRows FROM user_tables where table_name = unldTable;
    
FOR row in 1..countUNLDRows LOOP
    rowArray := emptyArrayType;
    FOR value in 1..valExtractArray.COUNT LOOP
        rowArray.extend();
        SELECT data_type INTO dataType FROM all_tab_columns where table_name = unldTable AND column_name = valExtractArray(value);
        
        IF dataType = 'VARCHAR2' THEN (SELECT valExtractArray(value) INTO value_to_char FROM current_table WHERE ROWNUM = row); 
        ELSIF dataType = 'DATE' THEN (SELECT TO_CHAR(valExtractArray(value),'YYYY/MM/DD') INTO value_to_char FROM current_table WHERE ROWNUM = row);  
        ELSIF dataType = 'NUMBER' THEN (SELECT TO_CHAR(valExtractArray(value)) INTO value_to_char FROM current_table WHERE ROWNUM = row);
        ENDIF;
        
        rowArray(value) := value_to_char;
    END LOOP;
    concatData := NULL;
    FOR item in 1..rowArray.COUNT LOOP
        IF item = rowArray.COUNT
        THEN concatData := (COALESCE(concatData,'') || rowArray(item));
        ELSE concatData := (COALESCE(concatData,'') || rowArray(item) || '|');
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
    UTL_FILE.PUTF(fHandle, concatData + '/n');
END LOOP;
UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(fHandle);
END;
```

Thanks,

Adam

Comment: I'm not sure what this line is doing `rowArray(value) := unldTable(row).valExtractArray(value);`. Isn't unldTable a Varchar2(240)?

Comment: I agree with Chrisrs2292; the compiler is complaining because it should complain. You are using array syntax with a string.

Also, you don't need to declare a different array type for each different variable.

And what is the intention behind COALESCE (concatdata, concatdata)?

Comment: Hi both, thanks for answering. unldTable contains a VARCHAR that is the name of the table we're interested in. I've updated code to try and treat as a table rather than array, but still no luck. What I'm trying to do here is dynamically create the flat file, which I've done by looping through each row in the table & adding each value in that row to an array. In the next step we go through & concatenate each value in the array and write that to a flat file.

Comment: Coalesce is there to replace Null with an empty string in concatenation, sorry have updated the PLSQL as it was incorrect.

Comment: You are right, `unldTable` is defined as a string, because you declared it as `unldTable VARCHAR2(240);` That's a string. If you want it to be a collection, just make it one of your existing collection types (or better still, define a single string collection type and reuse that for everything, instead of having three identical types with slightly different names).

Comment: The syntax for populating a variable from a query is `select x into y from z`, not `y := (select x from z);`

Comment: `rownum` is incremented for each row returned from a query, so `where rownum = 2` will never return anything. Also, a 'script' implies a set of sequential instructions in a text file, not compiled program code.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson I've tried to update in accordance with what you've said.
Comment 1 - Please see above, is that better? Trying to fill an array element with the output from a select.
Comment 2 - Is there any way to return a specific row from a table then? What I'm trying to do is loop through the table & write each row to a flat file... can you suggest how I should approach this? I think you can tell I've done lots of object oriented but little set-based.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson In response to the 'You are right...' comment - I don't want it to be a collection. I want it to be a database table object that I can process. Just the VARCHAR2 contains the CHAR name of the database table

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is just an overlook in your code. You define `unldTable` as a varchar, which is used correctly until you try to access it as if it were a varray on line 51

```
rowArray(value) := unldTable(row).valExtractArray(value);
```

Given that you have not defined it as a varray, `unldTable(row)` is making the interpreter believe that you are referring to a function.

**EDIT**

Now that you have moved on, you should resolve the problem of invoking SELECT statements on tables that are unknown at runtime. To do so you need to make use of [Dynamic SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/dynamic.htm); you can do it in several way, the most direct being an Execute immediate statement in your case:

```
mystatement := 'SELECT valExtractArray(value) INTO :value_to_char FROM ' || current_table || ' WHERE ROWNUM = ' || row; 
execute immediate mystatement USING OUT value_to_char;
```

Comment: Yes, problem is that the unldTable variable is a VARCHAR2 containing the name of a database table, need to reference the database table object itself rather than the VARCHAR. Please see code updated above... trying to reference as DB table rather than array, but still doesn't quite work.

Comment: You cannot reference a dynamic table name as you are trying to do ("FROM unldTable WHERE"). This won't compile because it looks for a table called `unldTable`. You must use dynamic sql to do this. Have a look at the constructs in [Performing SQL Operations with Native Dynamic SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/dynamic.htm). For instance `execute immediate my_string` .

Comment: Thanks a lot Antonio, will look into this

Comment: Looked into execute immediate but none of the examples seem to be similar to what I want to do. Could you give me any idea around how/where execute immediate could be used? Ty

Comment: I just uploaded my answer showing how to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to generate a cursor as

```
select [list of columns from GNC_MIG_CONTROL.DB_FIELD]
from   [table name from GNC_HDL_CREATION_PARAMS.UNLD_TABLE]
```

Assuming setup like this:

```
create table my_table (business_date date, id integer, dummy1 varchar2(1), dummy2 varchar2(20));
create table gnc_hdl_creation_params (unld_table varchar2(30), process_component varchar2(30));
create table gnc_mig_control (db_field varchar2(30), hdl_comp varchar2(30), hdl_meta_tag integer);

insert into my_table(business_date, id, dummy1, dummy2) values (date '2018-01-01', 123, 'X','Some more text');

insert into gnc_hdl_creation_params (unld_table, process_component) values ('MY_TABLE', 'XYZ');

insert into gnc_mig_control (db_field, hdl_comp, hdl_meta_tag) values ('BUSINESS_DATE', 'XYZ', '1');
insert into gnc_mig_control (db_field, hdl_comp, hdl_meta_tag) values ('ID', 'XYZ', '2');
insert into gnc_mig_control (db_field, hdl_comp, hdl_meta_tag) values ('DUMMY1', 'XYZ', '3');
insert into gnc_mig_control (db_field, hdl_comp, hdl_meta_tag) values ('DUMMY2', 'XYZ', '4');
```

You could build a query like this:

```
select unld_table, listagg(expr, q'[||'|'||]') within group (order by hdl_meta_tag) as expr_list
from   ( select t.unld_table
              , case tc.data_type
                    when 'DATE' then 'to_char('||c.db_field||',''YYYY-MM-DD'')'
                    else c.db_field
                end as expr
              , c.hdl_meta_tag
         from   gnc_hdl_creation_params t
                join gnc_mig_control c
                     on  c.hdl_comp = t.process_component
                left join user_tab_columns tc
                     on  tc.table_name = t.unld_table
                     and tc.column_name = c.db_field
         where  t.process_component = 'XYZ'
       )
group by unld_table;
```

Output:

```
UNLD_TABLE  EXPR_LIST
----------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MY_TABLE    to_char(BUSINESS_DATE,'YYYY-MM-DD')||'|'||ID||'|'||DUMMY1||'|'||DUMMY2
```

Now if you plug that logic into a PL/SQL procedure you could have something like this:

```
declare
    processComponent constant gnc_hdl_creation_params.process_component%type := 'XYZ';
    unloadSQL long;
    unloadCur sys_refcursor;
    text long;
begin
    select 'select ' || listagg(expr, q'[||'|'||]') within group (order by hdl_meta_tag) || ' as text from ' || unld_table
    into unloadSQL
    from   ( select t.unld_table
                  , case tc.data_type
                        when 'DATE' then 'to_char('||c.db_field||',''YYYY/MM/DD'')'
                        else c.db_field
                    end as expr
                  , c.hdl_meta_tag
             from   gnc_hdl_creation_params t
                    join gnc_mig_control c
                         on  c.hdl_comp = t.process_component
                    left join user_tab_columns tc
                         on  tc.table_name = t.unld_table
                         and tc.column_name = c.db_field
             where  t.process_component = processComponent
           )
    group by unld_table;

    open unloadCur for unloadSQL;

    loop
        fetch unloadCur into text;
        dbms_output.put_line(text);
        exit when unloadCur%notfound;
    end loop;

    close unloadCur;
end;
```

Output:

```
2018/01/01|123|X|Some more text
2018/01/01|123|X|Some more text
```

Now you just have to make that into a procedure, change `dbms_output` to `utl_file` and add your meta tags etc and you're there.

I've assumed there is only one distinct `unld_table` per process component. If there are more you'll need a loop to work through each one.

For a slightly more generic approach, you could build a [cursor-to-csv generator](http://www.williamrobertson.net/documents/refcursor-to-csv.shtml) which could encapsulate the datatype handling, and then you'd only need to build the SQL as `select [columns] from [table]`. You might then write a generic cursor to file processor, where you pass in the filename and a cursor and it does the lot.

**Edit:** I've updated my [cursor-to-csv generator](http://www.williamrobertson.net/documents/refcursor-to-csv.shtml) to provide file output, so you just need to pass it a cursor and the file details.